# Python script executing in different order that I want

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

For simplicity I'm posting here only two modules (the other modules have "pass" in them). **start.py** module worked right up until I changed something in **player.py** module, in the class *CreateNewPlayer* and now what happens is this:

I start with **start.py** from my command line but instead of first showing my intro (*splashcreen* function) it jumps straight to *CreateNewPlayer* right away.

What did I do wrong?

This is the first file **start.py**:

```
import sys
import custom_error
import player
import handler
import prompt
import game


def splash_screen():
    print chr(27) + "[2J"
    print "*" * 80
    print "***** Welcome to ZOMBIE ADVENTURE *****"
    print "*" * 80
    print "\nSelect option:"
    print "1. Start a new game"
    print "2. Load existing game"
    print "3. Quit"

    while True:
        action = prompt.menu()

        if action == 1:
            create_player = player.CreateNewPlayer()
            new_player = player.Player(create_player.name, create_player.age, create_player.male, create_player.inventory)

            print "\nYour name is %s and you're %d old." % (new_player.name, new_player.age)
            print "It is %s that you're a man." % new_player.male

            print "\n1. Continue to game"
            print "2. Back to main menu"
            action = prompt.menu()

            while True:
                if action == 1:
                    game.Engine.launchgame()
                elif action == 2:
                     exit(1)
                else:
                    custom_error.error(1)
                    # a_game = game.Engine('Room1')
                    # a_game.LaunchGame(new_player)
        elif action == 2:
             handler.load()
        elif action == 3:
             exit(1)
        else:
             custom_error.errortype(0)

splash_screen()
```

Now second file called **player.py**:

```
import sys
import custom_error
import prompt
import game

class Player(object):


     male = True
     inventory = []

     def __init__(self,name,age,male,inventory):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.male = male
        self.inventory = inventory

 class CreateNewPlayer(object):


     print chr(27) + "[2J"
     print "-" * 80
     print "Character creation"
     print "-" * 80

     name = raw_input("Type your character name > ")
     age = int(raw_input("Put down your age in numbers > "))
     male = True
     sex = raw_input("Are you a male or female? M/F > ")

     if sex.lower() == "m":
         male = True
     elif sex.lower() == "f":
         male = False
     else:
         print "Please type either 'M' or 'F'"
         pass

     inventory = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes within `CreatePlayerCharacter` are *class attributes*; all of the code within that class definition runs when the class is created, i.e. when the file is imported, rather than when a class instance is created.

Looking at your code so far, you would probably be better defining a class method `Player.create`:

```
class Player(object):

    ...

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        name = raw_input("Type your character name > ")
        ...
        return cls(name, age, male, [])
```

This can be accessed:

```
new_player = Player.create()
```

and will return a `Player` instance directly.

You should also remove `male` and `inventory` class attributes from `Player`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes when I put the code in function it's not a problem anymore. However, I haven't learned about class methods yet so is there a way to return those variables from `CreatePlayerCharacter`?

Comment: Yes, you can just `def create_player_character(): ... return name, age, male, []` then call `new_player = Player(*create_player_character())`. The class method is neater, and there's not much to learn!

Comment: Will definitely look into class methods after I'm done with this little game.
Another newbie question. What's with the `*` asterisk symbol? It's like magic = everything works now :) I know it stands for multiply. When I tried it without `*` it told me that I'm not putting in enough arguments for object `Player` to be instantiated.

Comment: oh i see that `*` is for unpacking arguments.

Comment: That's right, `*` unpacks a tuple to positional arguments, `**` a dictionary to keyword arguments. Close enough to magic!